# how to integrate iOS 12 Autofill in an app connecting to multiple web sites (browser as an example)?

Tags: ios, react-native, autofill

I am working on a browser-like App on iOS 12 that connects to multiple web sites.  How to support Autofill username/password?  Or how to seamlessly integrate with 1Password, LastPass etc password management apps?  Essentially, how to tell the iOS 12 QuickType bar the URL that a certain widget/page is for?  Without the url info, the QuickType bar provides all the passwords and it is a bad user experience.  How did Firefox or Chrome achieve the same on iPhone?  All the web sites are 3rd party web sites.  So I can't put a file on their servers.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open the third parties website (even if its in a WKWebView) and they support something like OAuth this could work. Firefox and Chrome are using WebViews so Apple determines the site you’re on and sends that to the password manager.

The other way would be by having the third party sites add your app bundle id to their .wellknown which as you said they can’t.

Comment: So it has to be WebViews?  Any way to make Autofill work with TextInput other than putting my app bundle ID under .wellknown?  Thanks for the info anyway.

Comment: Yes it has to be in a WebView loading the third party site or if it’s a text field in your app your bundle id has to be in the .wellknown.